# How can I add the numbers to my array in this code?

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to make a 3 dimensional list which contains all of the numbers. Example :
N=2
My array must have contain all of the variations :

```
000
001
002
003
010
...
210
211
212
213
```

How can I add the numbers to my array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int N;
cin >> N;

int array[N][2][4]={0};

    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2; ++j)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<4 ; ++k)
            { 
                cout << array [i][j][k]<< endl;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the number where you have the cout. You know `i`, `j` and `k` so you can generate your number from that. If you only want to print you don't need a an array for this.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not available in C++ standard. Use std::vector.

Comment: If you need only output, remove array from the code, leave std::cout << i << j << k << std::endl.

Comment: I need an array for my exercise.

Comment: I just do not know how can I add, that is why I write the question.

Comment: Multiply 100 times `i` and 10 times `j` and add these 2 numbers with `k` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I am having a hard time to understand you question. You just want to allocate memory dynamically? Then you may use the `new`statement.

Like in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr unsigned int DimensionZ = 4;
constexpr unsigned int DimensionY = 2;

using YZArray = int[DimensionY][DimensionZ];

int main() {

    unsigned int dimensionX{};
    if ((std::cin >> dimensionX) and (dimensionX > 0)) {

        
        YZArray* xyzArray = new YZArray[dimensionX]{};

        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < dimensionX; ++x)
            for (unsigned int y = 0; y < DimensionY; ++y)
                for (unsigned int z = 0; z < DimensionZ; ++z)
                    xyzArray[x][y][z] = 100 * x + 10 * y + z;

        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < dimensionX; ++x)
            for (unsigned int y = 0; y < DimensionY; ++y)
                for (unsigned int z = 0; z < DimensionZ; ++z)
                    std::cout << std::right << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << xyzArray[x][y][z] << '\n';

        delete[] xyzArray;
    }
}
```

Please enter 3 for the above exampe, then you will get your sequence.

---

But, because the answer is that simple, I guess it is wrong. My guess is that you want to have 3 parallel 1 dimensional arrays and then build the combinations of that. Please specify more clearly.